# How do I set parent div height based on height of tallest child?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have a row and two columns (one column will be flex for this example). I would like to set the height of the row to be the height of the tallest child element. I am having trouble doing this without explicitly setting the height of the row.

```css
.row {
  background: yellow;
}

.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: aqua;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://hypb.imgix.net/image/2017/12/kith-spongebob-squarepants-teaser-1.jpg?q=75&w=800&fit=max&auto=compress%2Cformat">
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <p>This column should match the height of the other column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make height of the parent div(`.row`) the height of the tallest child div (an image in the above example)?

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

p.s. I saw this resource [equal height columns in css](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) but surely there must be a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` in row. if give flex to parent then there is no need to give float property to child.

```css
.row {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
}

.column1 {

  width: 50%;
}
.column2 {

  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: aqua;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://hypb.imgix.net/image/2017/12/kith-spongebob-squarepants-teaser-1.jpg?q=75&w=800&fit=max&auto=compress%2Cformat">
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <p>This column should match the height of the other column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I asked, this wasn't as complex as I thought it would be.

Comment: Yes it not complex :)

Comment: If this answers help you then you can accept and upvote so it help others with similar problem. :)

Comment: And if you want to 50% 50% child width then you can just give flex-grow:1 to flex child

Answer (score 0):

Add style `display: flex;` on the div with class row